# PHP read file error

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get an end result which loads a txt file counts how many times each word has been used and echos the results. The code is used is given below.Looking forward for valuable suggestions...

```
<?php   
 $text = fopen("words.txt", "r"); 
 $textarray = explode(" ",$text); 
 foreach($textarray as $numbers) 
    { 
     if(isset($str_count[$numbers])) 
     $str_count[$numbers]++; 
        else
         $str_count[$numbers]=1; 
    } 

 foreach($str_count as $words => $numbers) 
 echo $words.": ".$numbers."<br>"; 

 ?>
```

Comment: What is your question, what doesn't work?

Comment: The first comment I would make is that you should swap the `explode()` for `preg_split('/\s+/', $text);` so you can account for multiple spaces, tabs, newlines etc.

Comment: besides the fact that you're not using PHP's built-in str_word_count() function to generate your list of words and frequencies, what exactly is the problem

Comment: Little sidenote, the `$numbers` variable in the first `foreach` loop should rather be named `$words`, as those are words from your text file, and not numbers.

Comment: What is the issue? What is the error? Put the error here and use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the begging of the file.

Comment: Whats the error? post it

Comment: When you open up a file with fopen, it will return a resource (the file handle), not its contents, thus on the second line $text will not contain file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, but there are a few things that need to be changed.

`fopen()` function opens up a file (in this case for reading) returns a resource (a handle of the file), which we use to read the file. It DOES NOT return file contents. If you need further information, please check [fopen() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).
I substituted `fopen()` with `file_get_contents()` just for the sake of simplicity.

Secondly, as @DaveRandom suggested, it would be a good idea to substitute `explode()` for `preg_split('/\s+/', $text);`, because that way it would be able to deal with multiple spaces. Of course, this is not necessary, but recommended.

And lastly, I found that with `preg_split('/\s+/', $text)` the script had an empty element, thus I added an `if` statement to make sure we do not add empty strings. This step is also not required, so if you do not need it, just remove the first if statement.

And here is the modified source code:

```
<?php   
$text = file_get_contents('words.txt');
$textarray = preg_split('/\s+/', $text);
foreach($textarray as $numbers) 
{ 
    if(empty($numbers)) {
        continue;
    }
    if(isset($str_count[$numbers])) 
        $str_count[$numbers]++; 
    else
            $str_count[$numbers]=1; 
} 

foreach($str_count as $words => $numbers) 
    echo $words.": ".$numbers."<br>"; 

?>
```